# Make all but a given set of crosses ilegal in systemverilog cross coverage

Tags: system-verilog

I am attempted to produce a cross in a covergroup that crosses two variables A and B.  I would like the cross to include a given subset of the crosses and make all others illegal.  Furthermore I don't want to group up any of the valid crosses in a single bin.  I can express the valid crosses in terms of bins of the A and B coverpoints, i.e. I'm looking for something like this:

```
my_cross : cross A, B {
   bins a_subset = binsof(A.bin0) && binsof(B.bin0);
   bins b_subset = binsof(A.bin1) && binsof(B.bin1);
   illegal_bins illegal = default;
}
```

However the above will group up multiple crosses in the two bins, so a_subset will be a single bin containing every cross that has a member of both A.bin0 and B.bin0.  I want a_subset to be multiple bins, one for each cross specified in the subset.

A plain coverpoint allows you to do this kind of thing by placing [] after the bin name, however this doesn't work for crosses (SystemVerilog LRM doesn't say you can do it and MTI doesn't accept it).

```
my_cross : cross A, B {
   bins a_subset[] = binsof(A.bin0) && binsof(B.bin0);
   bins b_subset[] = binsof(A.bin1) && binsof(B.bin1);
   illegal_bins illegal = default;
}
```

The resulting cross will be rather large so I'd rather not do the black-list alternative (i.e. make everything I don't want explicitly illegal) as I might miss invalid combinations, or explicitly write out everything allowable as it will be laborious, huge and tricky to alter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered a solution, though it doesn't do exactly what I want it's good enough.

You can use the ! operator in front of a binsof(b1) intersect(b2) expression.  Which inverts it (so excludes everything the expression includes).  There are various values of A which pair with particular values of B.  I can express the values of B that are allowed via the binsof(b1) intersect(b2) construct and invert it to get the non-allowed values of B.  Then use this to contruct the illegal bins.

This does mean invalid values of A would still get included in the cross, however those values are all listed as illegal in the A coverpoint so they get excluded.

I end up with something like this:

```
my_cross : A, B {
    illegal_bins illegal =
     ((binsof(A.bin0) ||
      (binsof(A.bin1))   &&
     !binsof(B) intersect {B_VAL1, B_VAL2}) || 
     ((binsof(A.bin2) ||
      (binsof(A.bin3))   &&
     !binsof(B) intersect {B_VAL1, B_VAL3});
}
```

Where B_VAL1 and B_VAL2 pair with the values from bin0 and bin1 from A and B_VAL1 and B_VAL3 pair with the values from bin2 and bin3.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that a cross contains too many tuples to manage, then consider creating coverpoints with a restricted set of bins that you put into the cross. For example

```
bit [7:0] A, B;
covergroup cg;
  Acp : coverpoint A {
    bins set1[] = {/* some limited set of bins*/ };
}
  Bcp : coverpoint B {
    bins set1[] = {/* some limited set of bins*/ };
}
  my_cross: cross Acp, Bcp;
endgroup
```

Also, look at some of the more complex bin expressions added in 1800-2012.

Comment: I don't think that will quite work.  I don't want to group any crosses together in the same bin and the desired crosses aren't simple enough to express them like that.  For example A has aitem1, aitem2, ..., aitemN, B has bitem1, bitem2, ..., bitemN.  aitem1 goes with bitem1 and bitem2 as does aitem2, however aitem3 goes with bitem1 and bitem3 and (aitem3, bitem2) is an illegal combination.

So just seperating out A and B into small sets of bins would only work if I made multiple different crosses.

I suspect I can't do precisely what I want in systemverilog.